# What is the difference between msg.sender and from address in solidity smart contracts, are both the same who are initiating the transaction?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I am just starting out with the solidity and the smart contracts but i am confused like what is the difference between msg.sender and from address in ERC20 guidelines for the creation of smart contracts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **msg.sender** refers to the account that is calling the function it could be an EOA (Externally Owned Account) or a contract Address.
- **from** is a parameter for the function.

Example:

```
// Send an amount from any address to any address    
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(from, to, amount);
        return true;
    }

// Send an amount from the function caller to any address    
function transferFromCaller(address to, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, to, amount);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

msg.sender is actually the address that you use when calling the function. This is a global variable that you don't define. As far as I understant, in a Token contract, "from" is the address of the account you want to use to spend some amount of token.